# How to see download sync speed when syncing the Bitcoin 0.17.1 Blockchain on Ubuntu 18?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, synchronization

I'm syncing the bitcoin 0.17.1 blockchain from the beginning on Ubuntu 18 using Bitcoin Core Qt gui client. Is there a way to see the download speed of the Bitcoin Blockchain and how much time I have left to get it fully synced?

Comment: Do you care about download speed (Mb/s) specifically? Or just 'time until it is synced'? With a fast internet connection, CPU is usually the bottleneck to getting synced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care about overall sync performance, the download speed is usually not the bottleneck.

If you want to calculate your pure download speed, you can use `getnettotals`. There is a value `totalbytesrecv` (amount of bytes received since the Bitcoin Core instance has been started).

You can calculate the speed by reading the sync start time out of your `debug.log` (or you eventually wrote down the sync start time manually).

**But be aware** that the CPU intense validation of blocks may have (very likely) throttle your download.

Comment: It currently in an ubuntu vm with 8 cpu core and 3gb rm allocated. Is that enough or should i allocate more?

Comment: @Patoshi You should also configure bitcoind to actually use that memory, with the `dbcache=` config file entry.